# Detect mobile browser or mobile app is used with CSS only

Tags: android, css, iphone, email, mobile

I am struggling with emails so I can use only CSS.

The issue is that outlook/gmail apps in dark mode are inverting colours as we all know.
But mobile browsers (chrome, safari, duck duck go) even if having dark mode applied, do not inverse all colours the same way mobile apps do.

What do I want to achieve?
I want not to use my RWD CSS styles in mobile browsers, but still be able to use it on mobile apps.

Is there any technique that can help me to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect whether a user is viewing your email in a mobile browser or a mobile app, so you cannot use CSS to target specific platforms. However, there are a few options you can consider to address the issue of color inversion in dark mode on mobile devices:

Use high-contrast colors: Choose colors that have a high contrast ratio, such as black and white, to ensure that your email is legible in both light and dark mode.

Use the color-scheme media query: The color-scheme media query allows you to specify different styles for different color schemes (e.g., light mode and dark mode). For example:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  /* styles for light mode */
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* styles for dark mode */
}
```

Use the @media media query to target specific devices: You can use the @media media query to apply specific styles to certain devices. For example:

```
@media (min-width: 601px) {
  /* styles for devices with a minimum width of 601px */
}
```

This can help you apply different styles to different devices, but it is not a foolproof solution since you cannot target specific platforms (e.g., mobile browsers vs. mobile apps).

It's worth noting that some email clients, such as Gmail and Outlook, do not support the color-scheme media query or the @media media query. In these cases, you may need to rely on using high-contrast colors to ensure that your email is legible in both light and dark mode.

Comment: Hi Мартин. Using `@media ()` is not working on all email clients.